# Probability of someone getting a straight flush in a 5 player game

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Say you are playing a version of poker where you get dealt $5$ cards from a regular $52$ card deck. Also let's assume we have $5$ players.

**Question**: What is the probability that *at least one* of the players is dealt a [straight flush](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_poker_hands)?

The probability that the first player gets dealt a straight flush is relatively easy to compute simply by counting: there are $4*10$ ways to get a straight flush and there are $52\choose {5}$ ways to deal $5$ cards. But if you want start looking at conditional probabilities things get gnarly since what the other players get affects your chances of getting a straight flush.

A natural things is to do is to try to enumerate all possibilities but there are quite a lot of them, namely: $${52\choose 5}{48\choose 5}{44\choose 5}{40\choose 5}{36\choose 5}$$

Also since the probability of someone getting a straight flush is so low a Monte Carlo simulation might not correctly estimate the actual probability.